# What is the RegEx to just return the last part of the URL

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to take a URL string and use regEx to return `partTwo`?

```
A: http://www.example.com/part1/part-two
B: http://www.example.com/part0/part-two/
C: http://www.example.com/part1/part-two/?id=1
D: http://www.example.com/part1/part-two.html/?id=1
```

Note: change part-two into partTwo (removing - and make the next character into capital)

Comment: None of your examples have the string "partTwo" in them. :(

Comment: I was hoping regEx could take part-two and change it to partTwo replacing -t into T

Comment: use a url parser, not a regex.

Comment: regexs don't replace. they just match against strings looking for patterns.

Comment: A is quite different from B-D.

Comment: YH : so ignoring . and ? and anything after the last /

Comment: @DanielA.White if you're confident replacing -t with T is not possible I can ammend the question

Comment: some other valid url cases: `part1/part-two.html?id=1`, `part1/part-two?id=1` (no final slash) `part1/part-two.html#something` (url hash) — This is why @DanielA.White comment to use a url parser is a better approach than regex. You already have a URL parser if you're running in a browser. `var s4="http://www.example.com/part1/part-two/?id=1"; var u4=new URL(s4); var path=u4.pathname`

Comment: URL parser is an extra dependency that I do not want to introduce into the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like by "the last part", you mean "the part before the query string or after the last slash if there's no query string", right?

Well, you can find the bit after the last slash with this: `/([^\/]+)$/`

And you can find the bit between a slash and the first question mark like this: `/([^\/]+)\?/`.

Neither of those will work for example D, though, as it has another slash before the query string. For that example, you'd need something like this: `/([^\/]+)\/\?/`

So if we combine all those, we get something like this: `/([^\/]+)(?:\/?\?|$)/`

As for converting to camel case, you'll have to do that separately, and there's no regex that can capitalize for you; you'll need to use a regex to capture all hyphen-letter combos one by one and replace them with the matched letter `.toUpperCase`.

**EDIT** Just realized the regex I gave you won't match B. So you need another case for a slash at the end, which makes the final regex this: `/([^\/]+)\/?(?:\?|$)/` . This says "match a string of non-slashes followed by possibly a slash, then definitely followed by either a question mark or the end of the string".

Comment: interesting thank you for taking the time and explaining :)

Comment: Sure. Also keep in mind that for example D, it will capture the entire "part-two.html"; if you want to remove the extension, you can apply the replacement on the result: `value.replace(/\.[^.]+$/, "")` (That's "a dot, followed by anything that's not a dot until the end of the string".)

Comment: it was not a requirement for me personally I just thought I ask a question to which more people can use answer of :)